# What could I use to read epub books on OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, ebook, epub

I would prefer a good and free solution for reading `epub` books on OS X.

It looks that by default OS X is not able to open epub books.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a practical ePub book reader program for Mac OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/22497/is-there-a-practical-epub-book-reader-program-for-mac-os-x)

Comment: Funny, iBooks was bundled with 10.9 in Fall 2013 and supports EPUB + PDF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/)

[ePubRead Firefox Addon](http://www.epubread.com/en/)

[Crossplatform Sony book reader](http://ebookstore.sony.com/download/)

[Mac OS X Port of FBReader](http://gobunov.ru/projects)

[Adobe Digital Editions](http://www.adobe.com/products/digitaleditions/)

Comment: Great list. It's just too bad that Adobe Digital Editions is so horrid.

Comment: Yeah, considering adobe *should* be peerless for digital media, and yet reader and DE are garbage.

Comment: Calibre doesn't seem to show the content of epub books

Answer (score 3):

[Stanza](http://www.lexcycle.com/download-macintosh) is a very good epub reader for OSX that is free.

Comment: Down vote, link doesnt work!

Comment: Stanza was the best ereader but Amazon bought it and they don't want a epub reader

Answer (score 2):

Scarlett in the Mac App Store.

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/scarlett/id457009670?mt=12

Comment: No longer free.

Answer (score 1):

I use **Calibre** on my desktop machines; it's very feature rich and can convert to and from `.epub` so you can use it with most of the "specialty" readers. You can even "tweak" your books to fix minor typos and oddities from conversions. I don't think that is up to the normal Mac usability, but it does work.

I've also used the **Kobo** reader to read various epubs; it has some nicer page layout than Calibre and allows comments and highlighting that is pretty unique to Kobo.  I'll admit I haven't used it on Mac, but I think it's great on Windows and Android. I'm pretty sure it's **Stanza** on my iPad, though.

Ted

Answer (score 0):

http://calibre-ebook.com/  might be a bit full featured but will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

[Bookle](http://bookle.stairways.com) is a native epub viewer for OS X, but its development seems to have stopped at a kind of a beta stage. It doesn't support searching, and I didn't really like the full screen mode or the library model.

[image]

I have used calibre's ebook-convert to convert some epub files to plain text:

```
/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert input.epub output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Other alternatives:

E-Book Preview, http://macbookreader.com/wp/bookviewer (v.5.7 is the last full-featured free version)
Bookreader Free, http://macbookreader.com/wp/  (there's also a paid version)
Kitabu, www.kitabu.me
Clearview, Canoe Software (App Store)

Stanza was freeware, copies are still lurking on the Internets.

Answer (score -2):

[Amazon Kindle for Mac](http://www.amazon.com/gp/kindle/mac) works quite well.  You can download it directly from Amazon, or get it via the [Mac App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/kindle/id405399194?mt=12).

Comment: This reads .mobi files not .epub

Comment: Bah, I forgot that I had to convert them using Calibre.

Answer (score -2):

http://www.zamzar.com/convert/epub-to-pdf/

Convert the EPUB into PDF for free.  They email you the converted file in 2 minutes.  Nothing to download, no trial, no partial download with a lure to buy the real deal.
Real deal.

You're welcome.

Comment: Are you in some way affiliated? We need to know that.

Comment: and reading epubs is much better than pdfs as you the user can change the font and the word wrap